# How to copy muliselected cells from one datagridview to another?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

All I have seen so far are ways to copy a whole row to another datagridview, but I would like to copy only the values of the highlighted (selected) cells as i drag down my mouse (like for an 8x3 grid). How would you do this? This is on windows form .net framework. I am getting an error when I try to transfer the cell value to a cell in datagridview2. The error says "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Here is a reference https://youtu.be/MK-vfM2uqY4

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 24){
            foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells){
                for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<= 3; j++){
                        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = null;//error occurs
                        else
                            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = cell.Value; //error occurs
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else

            MessageBox.Show("Select the correct number of cells");
    }
```

Comment: Need more detail to understand the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it already. Hope it is clearer

Comment: Which line of code gives you error? The senior gridview has enough rows and columns to accommodate values from first gridview.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Somewhere at the last two forloops (i and j). This is what the error says "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"

Comment: Can you debug and figure out where that somewhere is? How many columns and rows you have in second gridview.

Comment: The second gridview has 8 rows and 3 columns (which is how much I should highlight on the first gridview). The error is from doing both forloops (i and j) for each selected cell, which exceeds the 8 rows 3 columns of gridview2. I do not know how to get the value of each cell (cell.Value) without using the foreach loop.

Comment: if you have 8 rows and 3 columns then the the for loops should be `for(int i=0; i<8; i++)` and`for(int j=0; j< 3; j++)`. You can re-check the basics for arrays and indexing.